# Matrices with a given property over $GF(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be a $n \times n$ matrix over $GF(2)$, where $n$ is odd. How many choices of $M$ is possible such that $M M^T=J$, where $M^T$ denotes the transpose of $M$, and $J$ is the matrix of all ones.

(Of course, if $M$'s first row is a binary vector with odd number of ones, and the rest of the rows of $M$ are same, then we have the desired property. I am specifically interested when all rows of $M$ are different.)

Comment: What do you mean with GF(2)?

Comment: @GianlucaFaraco It is another notation for $\mathbb F_2$

Comment: @Mathmo123 thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The $(i,j)$ entry of $M M^T$ is the dot product of the $i$'th and $j$'th rows of $M$.  Over $GF(2)$, what this means is that for any two rows, the number of entries where both rows have $1$ is odd.  In particular, this is true for $i=j$, so each row has an odd number of $1$'s.

Consider the graph $G_n$ whose vertices are the subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ of odd cardinality, with an edge $(s,t)$ if $|s \cap t|$ is odd.  Each clique of size $k \le n$ in this graph corresponds to
$k! S(n,k)$ matrices whose rows are the members of the clique, where $S(n,k)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind.  Thus the number 
of matrices is $\sum_{k=1}^n c(n,k) k! S(n,k)$ where $c(n,k)$ is the number of $k$-cliques in the graph $G_n$.

For $n$ from $1$ to $8$ I get 
$1, 2, 22, 176, 14416, 461312, 272922112, 34934030336$, a sequence which seems not yet to be in the OEIS.

EDIT:
The triangle of coefficients $c(n,k)$ starts like this, if my programming is correct:

$$\matrix{1 &\cr2 &0 &\cr4 &3 &0 &\cr8 &12 &0 &0 &\cr16 &60 &60 &15 &0 &\cr32 &240 &480 &120 &0 &0 &\cr64 &1008 &5040 &8820 &7560 &3780 &1080 &\cr128 &4032 &40320 &131040 &120960 &60480 &17280 &2160 &\cr256 &16320 &342720 &2656080 &8739360 &17735760 &26071200 &29513700 &26254800 &\cr
}$$
Again, it doesn't seem to be in the OEIS.

Comment: thanks! I actually wanted to compute $c(n,n)$ i.e. no. of cliques of size $n$, and I rephrased it as the above problem. So do you know how to find $c(n,k)$ or at least its asymptotic values?